# How to transform a XML using XSLT only modifying a node that's required?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML only to replace a node name with another, but the XSLT that I framed is messing up the transformed XML. This might be a small issue that I might have overlooked, but am stuck with this from a long time.

Input XML that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataCollection>
    <queryConst language="DBSQL">
        <queryUsed>
            SELECT EMP.FirstName, EMP.LastName FROM (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM
            employees WHERE EmployeeID &lt; 10) AS EMP
        </queryUsed>
    </queryConst>
    <record>
        <old>
            <Employees>
                <FirstName>James</FirstName>
                <LastName>Gosling</LastName>
            </Employees>
        </old>
    </record>
    <record>
        <old>
            <Employees>
                <FirstName>Rod</FirstName>
                <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
            </Employees>
        </old>
    </record>
</dataCollection>
```

The XSLT used is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dataCollection/queryConst/@language">
        <xsl:attribute name="language">DBVIEW</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dataCollection/record/old/Employees">
        <xsl:element name="TABLE">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output XML that I want is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataCollection>
    <queryConst language="DBVIEW">
        <queryUsed>
            SELECT EMP.FirstName, EMP.LastName FROM (SELECT FirstName,
            LastName FROM employees WHERE EmployeeID &lt; 10) AS EMP
        </queryUsed>
    </queryConst>
    <record>
        <old>
            <TABLE>
                <FirstName>James</FirstName>
                <LastName>Gosling</LastName>
            </TABLE>
        </old>
    </record>
    <record>
        <old>
            <TABLE>
                <FirstName>Rod</FirstName>
                <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
            </TABLE>
        </old>
    </record>
</dataCollection>
```

Any help / tips / suggestions on the above is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `xsl:copy` from the template matching `Employees`. Also, there's no need to use `xsl:element` when the element name is known. Try simply:

```
<xsl:template match="dataCollection/record/old/Employees">
    <TABLE>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </TABLE>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note also that a `match` *pattern* is not a `select` *expression*. You don't need to use the path unless you have other `Employees` nodes elsewhere in the input XML. With the given example,

```
<xsl:template match="Employees">
```

would be quite sufficient.